# "buildozer android debug" "TypeError" crash

Tags: android, python, typeerror, kivy, python-3.4

So Yes I'm trying to build my first android app with kivy and buildozer. This is an error that I've searched for but haven't found a conclusive answer to. I'd give more details but I'm not sure how to read the output

Here is the end of the readout:

```
----------
id: 117 or "extra-google-webdriver"
     Type: Extra
     Desc: Google Web Driver, revision 2
           By Google Inc.
           WebDriver
           Install path: extras/google/webdriver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.17', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 961, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 157, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 394, in install_platform
    self._install_android_packages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 357, in _install_android_packages
    if ver and ver > v_build_tools:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > str()
```

The Full output: http://pastebin.com/PKVC7rmL

The Buildozer.spec file:
    [app]

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = Om Number Converter

# (str) Package name
package.name = Omnum

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version = 1.2.0

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = True


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned     from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
#
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#     [app]
#     source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns]
#     license
#     data/audio/*.wav
#     data/images/original/*
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#     [app@demo]
#     title = My Application (demo)
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#     images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#     buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Buildozer supports Python 3, it uses Python-for-android to compile your APK. Python-for-android does not support Python 3. You need to make sure your code works with Python 2.7 and run buildozer using Python 2.7 to compile for Android.

Comment: ok, so I tested my code running "python" instead of "python3." How do I run buildozer with python 2?

Comment: You install it into Python 2, just like you did with Python 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am a noob in this area. And it seems to be unfortunate that I decided to learn python 3 first , rather than learning python 2 and waiting for full adoption of python 3

Comment: It is hard to know which one to start with during this period of transition. However almost everything you've learned for Python3 will still apply to Python2, so it's not really a waste of time.